# Need to tranfer data from a hyperlink to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have an email, in which I am receiveing a downloadable link for a csv file. I do not want to download the data in my pc, instead I want to transfer the data directly to the google sheet.

Do anyone has the suggestions for this?

I tried and I am able to fetch the link from the email.

Comment: About `I tried and I am able to fetch the link from the email.`, can you provide your current script and the detail of the current issue of your script?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script.

```
function extractAndUploadLinks() {
  var spreadsheetId = '164BZRed9VfY5DxSLRv-FmGAnLNePdkvnewKpYAlPkCE'; // Replace with your Spreadsheet ID
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1'; // Replace with the sheet name
  var searchQuery = 'subject:Assign to Resolve Report'; // Replace with the desired subject

  var threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery);

  var links = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      var body = message.getBody();
      var extractedLinks = extractLinksFromBody(body);
      Logger.log(extractedLinks);
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(extractedLinks);
      Logger.log(response);
      // links = links.concat(extractedLinks);
    }
  }

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var numRows = links.length;

  if (numRows > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows, 1).setValues(links.map(link => [link]));
  }
}

function extractLinksFromBody(text) {
  var regex = /https?:\/\/[^\s]+/g;
  var matches = text.match(regex);
  return matches || [];
}
```